# TextWrangler macro for changing buffer?

Tags: macos, text-editors, macros, textwrangler

I'm using TextWrangler as my main editor and am looking for a macro command that can change the buffer I'm working on. It's really annoying having to touch the mouse each time I need to change file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look on the View menu for "Next Document" and "Previous Document". The default shortcut keys are ⌥⌘] (option-cmd-]) and ⌥⌘[ (option+command+[).

If the files are in different windows, use the standard OS X combination of ⌘+`

Comment: Thanks Doug it works but it navigates through documents in a strange way a bit unpredictable I could say(not top to bottom or bottom to top)  do you know why this is?

Comment: Nope, that's not clear to me. Sorry.

Comment: Found this "The Next/Previous document commands now work in MRU (most recently used) order. When closing a document, you will be taken to the most recently used document (previously you were taken to the next document in the list in the Documents Drawer)." -- from http://www.barebones.com/support/textwrangler/notes_tw21.html